# Google Load Balancer and App Engine 400 errors - how to find more detail?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am looking at my Google App Engine dashboard, I have a .NET Core Web API deployed and am processing somewhere between 5-10 requests per second, but I am also reporting a handful of 400 errors from the GCP HTTP Load Balancer and I don't know why.  I look at the Google Load Balancer logs and I also see a bunch of 400 errors on my primary POST endpoint.  This only happens on the POST endpoint.  I try to see the full body of the HTTP Request but I can't seem to find it, it looks like Google doesn't log it by default.

I have a .NET Core API running on Google App Engine Flex connected to Google Cloud SQL running PostGresSQL.

How can I get more detail either from the Load Balancer to find out exactly what requests are coming in and what is happening?  I have attached a sample of the requests/400 status responses below.

Thanks in advance.

See Google App Engine Requests VS 400 errors graph

[image: See Google App Engine Requests VS 400 errors graph]

See HTTP 400 Errors with HTTP Load Balancer

[image: See HTTP 400 Errors with HTTP Load Balancer]

Comment: The first step is to figure out where the errors are being generated, at the load balancer or the VM instance. Both log to Cloud Logging. The determine what the error number is. Your question states 40x and 400. It is important to understand what search error value means. Once you have data for each request, then you will be able to determine the next steps. For example, a 404 is debugged differently than a 403. Your question lacks details on what is deployed, the language/framework, error details, etc. Edit your question once you have details.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JohnHanley -- I have updated per your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: An HTTP 400 means **Bad Request**. You have posted a screenshot of a list of logs but no details on the bad request. Note: Do not post screenshots. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: @MMK830028 Did you manage to find any more info on this? Or some material that helped you get a better understanding?   I am getting this same error but if I host the API locally the same call works so I don't believe the request is formatted incorrectly